# referencing a ASP:TextBox from CodeFile

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have 2 ASP controls in a page called Play.aspx:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtGuess" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit Guess" OnClick="PostGuess" />
```

The code at the top of my page is:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" Debug="false" Inherits="Play" CodeFile="Play.aspx.vb" %>
```

In the CodeFile (Play.aspx.vb) I have a procedure called PostGuess which tries to reference the TextBox using the code: txtGuess.text

Visual Studio 2008 gives this error: Name 'txtGuess' is not declared.

When I access the page in a browser, I get: 'txtGuess' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

This is the contents of the Play.aspx.designer.vb:

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
Partial Public Class Play
Protected WithEvents Head1 As Global.System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlHead
Protected WithEvents form1 As Global.System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm
Protected WithEvents ScriptManager1 As Global.System.Web.UI.ScriptManager
Protected WithEvents LoginView1 As Global.System.Web.UI.WebControls.LoginView
End Class
```

It might be an easy fix, I am not very good at this, please help!

Answer (score 0):

Declaring

```
Protected WithEvents txtGuess As Global.System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox
```

in the Play.aspx.vb file should be the ticket.

Comment: Thanks, I think that has fixed it... onto the rest of the debugging now :P

Comment: Sorry, I spoke too soon.
Now the browser says System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Yep, its part of an SQL query:
sql = "INSERT INTO Guesses (GameID, UserId, GuessedWord, GuessOrder) VALUES (" & Session("GameID") & ", " & Session("UserID") & ", '" & txtGuess.Text & "', 1);"